# Analysing the spread of data of a variable

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, fuzzy

In my data set there are repeated measures where each subject is measured at three time points.I want to see how the data of a single variable is spread.That is to find groups so that I can categorize the variables values into two or three groups. Why I want is after analyzing the data I want to use them to create membership functions for fuzzy logic. So for example if I have a variable as BMI and I want to categorize it as low, normal, high I want to find out 3 regions from the data set where I can group the data into the three groups `low, normal, high`.
What sort of method, graph can I use to analyze this repeated measures variable.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked several times before, so please use the search function!

One dimensional data is easy.

1. Visjalize (e.g. histogram, kernel density estimation, etc.)
2. choose Intervals from the plot
3. split as desired.

Don't bother to build an algorithm for choosing two parameters that you might as well just read off the chart!

Comment: When there are repeated measures can I draw a histogram as I normally would. Should I take the mean value for the repeated measures for a particular individual when drawing it.